# Grails installation

Tags: grails

I am trying to install grails in my windows 7, I have installed JDK 1.7.0 and downloaded grails from its site and extracted in path "`C:\grails`", i have jdk in "`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0`". I have set environment variable `JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"` and `GRAILS_HOME = "C:\grails"` and added `"%GRAILS_HOME%\bin"` and `JAVA_HOME` to path from advanced settings. But when i try to run `"grails -v"` or `"grails help"` i get the error `"The system cannot find the path specified."`. I even changed my directory to  "C:\grails" and ran "grails -v" but it is still giving me the same error.

I dont know what is wrong with it, please help me installing this thing.
Thanks

Comment: `JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"` mustn't include 'bin'

Comment: Posted an answer, so that you can close the question ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"` mustn't include 'bin'

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to verify that Java is working correctly first by entering "java -version" at the command line.

When you say you extracted the zip into "`C:\grails`" does that directory now just have a single sub directory (i.e. "`grails-2.5.0`" or whatever version you downloaded), or does it contain a bunch of sub directories (bin, conf, dist, doc. etc)?

If the answer is the former, your GRAILS_HOME should point to "`C:\grails\grails-2.5.0`" instead of just `C:\grails\`